# options to solve browser compatibility issues?

Tags: css, cross-browser, javascript, compass-sass, css3pie

I am designing a web application with css3. Every one knows that lot of css3 properties like gradients, border-radius, box-shadow, animate, border-image, background-rgb, last-child, nth-child etc.. will not work in earlier IE versions such as IE8,7,6. some of the java script libraries like [css3 pie](http://css3pie.com/) can be used to make Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features such as gradients, border-radius, border-shadow, border-image(not Last-child, nth child properties) but some of my friends facing issues with that and told me that it is not reliable.

Is there any other js library or polyfills which will support most of the css3 decoration features including child properties without using filter like [compass](http://compass-style.org/)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using rails you can try compass: http://compass-style.org/

Comment: @Luccas sorry i forget to add that i m not allowed to use filter.

Comment: You probably meant `box-shadow` and `rgba(R,G,B,a)`. There is no such thing as `border-shadow` and `rgb(R,G,B)` is supported in IE since version 4. Personally, I think trying to emulate rounded corners or other *strictly decorative* features in older IE is horribly wrong as it means you have to feed precisely the older and *slower* browsers more code that they have to deal with, thus hurting performance while not even improving functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem of PIE css3 with ie is not trust issue, in some cases Pie framework does not work because it has not one of the below prerequisites:
1- the initialization path of pie or its prefixes i.e for backgrounds, is not correct.
 in this case you should check the path. the best practice is to place pie.htc next to your main page/frame or master page.
2- your final result in IE is rendered in quirk mode.
3- the page doctype is not defined or is not XHTML(transitional or strict) or html5.

for any of aboveproblems it could have a full book of conditions and situations.
but once you used it 3-4 times it becomes natural, although personally i do not suggest using  css3 frameworks for IE, because IE is naturally slower than other browsers in most cases and these frameworks make it even slower. and it usually it is not beneficial personally i prefer backward compatibility for my sites. where the content is seen more correctly than nice.