# different colored line using css

Tags: html, css

I have some idea to do the different colored line

1. Use it as an image (not good since i am going to use it all over my website and it will increase the http request)
   [image]
2. Define 4 or 5 classes(`widht=50px,height=5px,color=somecolor`) in css and use the classes in html. (I may need to use more than 20 span, i dont want to increase the number of DOM elements)

Can anyone tell me some other way to do do that different colored line using css and html?

Thanks

Comment: you are rolling in the deep my friend, I would go with the span using percent instead fixed px. Another option is to use canvas ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy that is not a wise choice since it is not supported by earlier IE versions.

Comment: yes, I know, it's just another option.

Comment: I think an image makes the most sense.  One little HTTP request isn't a big deal, especially since it will be cached after the first visit.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/). If you figure out how it works you can make the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert yes one little HTTP request isn't a big deal in small scale websites but not in large scale websites.

Comment: @Jelmer i have already seen this before. it is not supported by earlier IE versions. i asked a question regarding css3pie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197882/options-to-solve-browser-compatibility-issues

Comment: How big is this website?  I think there's something to be said for keeping your techniques sane and manageable and allowing an http request.  You can also use a sprite, although I don't know if the dimensions of the image lend itself to that.

Comment: @Prashanth please define "earlier IE versions" I do not recommend to optimise for IE 7 and below.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert thanks for your suggestion. i ll go for images if there is no other way. before that i just wanted to check for alternate ways

Comment: @ChrisHerbert: If you are thinking responsiveness the best way is using html+css, because you can use percent values, and in a 1600px width screen, you can have a big image

Comment: @Jelmer atleast it has to be supported by IE 8

Comment: That image is going to be very light no matter what the dimensions. Solid blocks of color compress very well.

Comment: @TomSarduy No need for that. Have a look at the posted image. It is repetitive so a repeat-x will do :)

Comment: @Jelmer: oh, right! I missed that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using css3.

apply this css to your div

```
.multicolor
{
 height:5px;
 width:100%;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue,indigo,violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red );
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue,indigo, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange,red );
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient( left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue,indigo, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange,red );
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue,indigo, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange,red );
 background-image: -khtml-linear-gradient( left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue,indigo, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange,red );
 background-image: linear-gradient( left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue,indigo, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange,red );
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EMdVZ/)

Comment: Nice. but it didn't support in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :before and :after pseudoelements.
The example below shows how you can get away from the gradient at the color joint.

```
.line {
height: 11px;
background: #d1d2d4; 
position: relative;
&:before, &:after  {
    content: '';
    height: 11px;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
}
&:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, green 50%);  
}
&:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, violet 50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;  
}
```

}

https://codepen.io/nektobit/pen/wjOdww